# Is the derivative of a continuous function integrable on a closed interval?

Tags: real-analysis

Say, if f', derivative of a continuous function f, is defined on [a,b], will it be Riemann Integrable on [a,b]?

Comment: A continuous function need not even have a derivative.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example. Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$f(x)=x^{3/2} \sin (1/x)$ if $x \ne 0$ and $f(0)=0.$

Then $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $[0,1].$

Compute $f'(x)$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ and show that $f'$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$. Hence $f$ is not Riemann interable.